# Android, cannot resolve a var in an object

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am pretty sure this is me having a brain fart on how Java var lifecycle works but still.

So I have two variables, name and pfpPath. In the object I am given a uuid and from that, I need to head to Firebase and extract data with the uuid in mind and put it in variables.
Problem is that inside the completeListener, the variables don't get recognized.

How do I fix that?

Code:

```
package com.example.create4me;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

public class ChatItem {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    String name, pfpPath, userID;
    public ChatItem(String userID){
        this.userID = userID;
        db.collection("users")
                .whereEqualTo("uuid", this.userID)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                                this.name = doc.get("username");        <---THIS
                                this.pfpPath = doc.get("profilePic");   <---AND THIS
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getPfpPath(){
        return this.pfpPath;
    }
    public String getUserID(){
        return this.userID;
    }
}
```

Error:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to your `OnCompleteListener` anon inner class instance, not the enclosing `ChatItem` instance. To refer to it, you can scope `this` as `ChatItem.this`.